# Output window of IntelliJ IDEA cuts output

Tags: intellij-idea, console-output

Looks like there is a limit on the number of lines it shows.

I couldn't find it in the settings.

***Is there a way to make IDEA keep everything in the Output window?***

Answer (score 295, accepted):

`Preferences/Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console`, check the box next to `Override console cycle buffer size`, set to a larger number than 1024 KB.

[image: Screenshot of the Setting Window]

Comment: What version of IntelliJ is that? I don't have Console under Editor > General in version 14. In fact, my General sub-elements are *very* different than the screen shot.

Comment: @E-Riz IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6 on Mac has all of those settings

Comment: This is a better answer than the chosen answer above, since it'll handle updates of IDEA without getting a conflict of the idea.properties-file.

Comment: Not effective on phpstorm 2019.1, why ???

Comment: Worked for me. The max number of KB that work without intelliJ warning that "large buffer size can cause performance degradation" is 20480, at least on my computer and intelliJ version.

Answer (score 139):

Couldn't get more votes to close the question so I have to answer it myself.

IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the specified buffer size (Kb). Older lines are deleted.
# In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
```

Comment: is this kilobytes or megabytes?

Comment: @bharal It says in comment that it's Kb.

Comment: See comment in file:

# This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the specified buffer size (Kb).
# Older lines are deleted. In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled

Also, remember to udpaet settings after upgrade (like 12-> 13) as it creates new .properties

Comment: For my distro (Arch), `idea.properties` is located at `/usr/share/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/bin/idea.properties`. Note that for Linux (unlike Mac) you don't need to create a copy of this file.

Comment: For my distro (OS X) it was `vi "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties"`

Comment: `idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled` worked for me +1.

Comment: Does it works also for the terminal window?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't.