# Capture all logs when using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, logging

Is there a way that all logs (or even println) in IntelliJ's terminal will be saved into a file?
Or is there a setting that it won't get overwritten?

It's usually overwritten if the logs are already long.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to redirect console output to a log file in IntelliJ like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736020/is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-log-file-in-intellij-like-eclipse)

Comment: @Peter i've set that but it seems that there are no logs T_T maybe there's something wrong with my settings

Comment: @mengmeng 1) Do you use Gradle? 2) Make sure that the output file has write permissions.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov @Peter thank you for your comments. I have stupidly realized what is the real solution to my problem. I didn't know that there's a setting in the terminal to to display infinite line. I thought that `docker logs` are always overwritten after x lines. :(

Comment: I had similar problem, here's what helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763996/output-window-of-intellij-idea-cuts-output